# Actionscript 3: Listeners not working after child is removed, then added again

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

I have some code that adds a "back" button to the stage that has its own code, and clicking it removes the button and brings users back to a title screen. However, when the "back" button is reintroduced to the stage, none of its listeners work.

```
public class BACK extends SimpleButton {


    public function BACK() {
        // constructor code
        trace('back button on stage');
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, startUp);
    }
    function startUp(ev:Event): void{
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoTitle);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, backBtnCleanUp);
    }
    function gotoTitle(ev:MouseEvent): void{
        trace('gototitle called');
        MovieClip(root).gotoTitle();
    }
    function backBtnCleanUp(ev:Event): void{
        trace('back button cleanup called');
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, startUp);
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoTitle);
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, backBtnCleanUp);
    }
}
```

the trace function executes when it is first added to the stage, but not when it is added again after being removed. This is the code (from Main) that both adds and removes it.

```
    function gotoHelp(): void{  // transitions to the help screen
        cleanTitle();
        addChild(helpBG);
        addChild(backBtn);
        backBtn.x = 550;
        backBtn.y = 200;
    }
    function gotoTitle(): void{ //goes to the title screen
        trace('going to title');
        removeChild(backBtn);
        removeChild(helpBG);
        titleStartUp();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you actually construct a new instance of your `Back` button?

Comment: Within the gotoHelp function, where it's named 'backBtn'. Its linked to the BACK class. Or am I not understanding the meaning of the word 'construct' in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a **new instance** of your `BACK` button every time you need to show it, or remove this line from `backBtnCleanUp` function : ( not tested )

```
removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, startUp);
```

Comment: removing the listener remover worked. Why though? Why is that listener not re-added when the instance is created again?

Comment: if you remove ` ADDED_TO_STAGE ` listener and you dont create a new instance of you ` BACK ` button the ` startUp ` function is never re-executed.